# Does delete() instantly frees memory or runtime.GC() is required to free it up?

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, go, runtime

I have a map

```
myMap := map[string]string
myMap['hello'] = 'world'
myMap['foo'] = 'bar'
```

When I delete an element from myMap like,

```
delete(myMap['hello'])
```

Does it **instantly** frees up memory or does it frees memory after garbage collector is run. 
If it frees up memory after garbage collector is run, Does running `runtime.GC()` will clean up the memory instantly.

Also is `runtime.GC()` resource hungry ? or Its okay to run `runtime.GC()` after every `delete()` function

**Update 2:**
Forget what my program does (basically update 1)  
Check this link http://play.golang.org/p/Wb8-4qWyf4 
There is a subroutine to add to a Map every 10 Microsecond 
There is a subroutine to delete from map every 1 Microsecond (10 times faster that adding) 
Run this program in your local machine, you will find that its keeps on occupying more and 
more RAM slowly. (Slowly because I added a sleep time, otherwise computer will hang)

**Update 1**

My program fetches 5000 rows of data from database every minute and stores it in a map called datastore.
There are 100 subroutines running which processes each rows from datastore. It takes much time to process one row (less than a second)
If data is successfully processed it is deleted "delete()" from datastore, but within next minute next 5000 is fetched and added to datastore.
I am keeping maximum of 20,000 rows in datastore. Which is not much (200 MB at max)
 
After processing millions of rows, application start taking 100% of RAM and gets Killed by kernal at the end.
It should not happen if delete() was clearing the memory instantly.

Comment: You should not use this function. Let the garbage collector manage the garbaging at the best times.

Comment: But my program takes upto 17GB memory and then killed by kernel

Comment: Then you have another problem that `runtime.GC()` won't solve : you're not releasing the memory (or you use too much of it).

Comment: Then you probably have other problems. For example, you may be confused about the life time of your data and hold onto it (preventing GC) longer than necessary. You could try `delete()`ing it, but to do that right you need to know *when* it's garbage; but if you know that you could simply stop holding references to it. Or you're just trying to stuff far too much data into RAM. In short, we can better help you if you describe your problem and roughly what your program is doing.

Comment: I have updated What my application is designed for

Comment: Without knowing what are your routines doing, it is hard to help you. However, if you are processing strings, take note that if there is a reference to any part of the string, for example a slice to the first character, the whole string will remain in memory. If you need just a small subset of the string, it is better to copy it so the old string can be GC'ed.

Comment: Forget what my program does, check this program http://play.golang.org/p/Wb8-4qWyf4 in short this is what is happening

Comment: + Updated the question accordingly

Comment: Map access is not concurrent-safe. You should put a Mutex around any addition/modification/deletion in your map. However, I'm not sure it is the cause of your problems.

Comment: @siritinga How do I add mutex ?

Answer (score 1):

You are executing your `deleter` only once. In addition, `map` access is not concurrent-safe so you need to add Mutex around your code.

Here is a fix, that will not grow with time: http://play.golang.org/p/GWQ2hJiySP

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var datastore = make(map[int64]string)

var m sync.Mutex

func adder() {
    var count int64 = 0
    for {
        m.Lock()
        datastore[count] = "kjnbhjsdhgvsaghbsdbasjsabjhsabasbdjashdbashdbjasbdhasbdjbdjbdjhabjds"
        m.Unlock()
        count++
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Microsecond)

    }
}

func deleter() {
    for {
        m.Lock()
        for key, _ := range datastore {
            delete(datastore, key)
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Microsecond)
        }
        m.Unlock()
    }
}

func main() {
    // Start adding stuff to datastore (with MORE sleep time = 10 Microsecond)
    go adder()

    // Wait for some time
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    // Start deleting stuff from datastore (With LESS sleep time = 1 Microsecond)
    go deleter()

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Hour)
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

I have put the lock in the `deleter` around the whole loop. It should be only necessary around the `delete`, however, you should not delete entries that way, with a range, because modifying the map can change the order of the iteration, so this structure should not be used in a real-life program.

Comment: I dont want to delete all the stuff at once, it has to be deleted one by one, Suppose for every loop in deleter(), there is one tasks being performed, it task is successful it has to be deleted else it should not be deleted.

Comment: By the way, your program is still consuming more and more memory. Did not solve the memory consumption issue :(

Comment: Then it is OK, just lock the delete() and it will be fine. You should also lock the map when reading! There is a RWMutex that allows locking for reading or writing, so reading can be done concurrently. If not, just using Mutex will be OK.

Comment: I'm having no memory issues with my program, it is stable using about 2.3 MB of RAM... are you using the same, with the latest Go version 1.2 or 1.2.1?

Comment: go version go1.1.2 linux/amd64

Comment: Try the latest release, it could be a bug in your version.

Comment: go version go1.1.2 linux/amd64, same issue :(

Comment: Well, same version, same issue ;) try to update it to 1.2.1 and check again.

Comment: Sorry, Pasted wrong data. I meant: go version go1.2.1 linux/amd64, same issue :(  http://play.golang.org/p/QnO_F5x3Zx

Comment: You `deleter` is only executed once. You need to loop it, check my code.